# Ionic 1, how to reload a part of page, not the whole page

Tags: ionic-framework, refresh, reload, partial-page-refresh

I'm working in app using ionic 1, It's a social network app.

My problem is that I want to reload a value, not the whole page and I don't know how to do it.

This my example from my news feed:
[image]

I want when I click like or comment the new value appear without reload all page.

For now I use:

> $window.location.reload(true)

PS:
When a user click in like, a new like add in database and the number of likes add +1, so when I reload page the new number of likes appear.

So again the problem is how to reload a part of page, not the whole page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ragnar, try to bind the like value in a $scope variable and then when the process to add the like in database is complete (process.then()..., for example) update the $scope variable.

If you are using an array to fill this, get the $index (generated by ng-repeat) and update only the $scope variable for the related item

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I didn't get your answer well, so I bind my like with a $scope.newLike for example, but after that how to show the $scope.newLike in ng-repeat for every publication??

Comment: How did you retrieve this information from server? 
You can use a function update(object, repeatIndex) and update only one value instead of your list of items.
If you retrieve like this for example: [ {person: Kamaw, likes: 1, comments: 0} ], when you update the likes, you can return the new value (object) from server and update the old $scope variable.